# Unable to establish connection to sql-server using pyodbc on Windows 10

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc as sql
import pandas as pd

source_db_config = {
    'Trusted_Connection': 'yes',
    'driver': '{SQL Server}',
    'server': '.',
    'database': 'AdventureWorksDW2017',
    'autocommit': True,
}


source_connect = sql.connect(**source_db_config)
```

cannot connect with sql server. It's showing OperationalError:

> OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (2)')

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the error correct? Does the server exist? Are you running your code on the same machine as the database? Is SQL Server running? `pyodbc` works just fine on Windows, I'm using it myself right now.

Comment: Is your server configured to use Shared Memory or TCP? Try using `localhost` instead of `.`. Also try the tutorial in [Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15), after installing the latest drivers shown in [Configure Development Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Shared Memory is ideal, enable it if you can, then stick with `.`. Obviously only works on the local machine, not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Python required additional driver to be install to get connect with Databases.

In your case download python driver for sql server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: I already have installed python driver for sql server. I try to install the updated version but even showing the same error.

Comment: @ankit.jbp Windows Authentication doesn't require SSL. The issue you linked to is unrelated. I've been using Python and pyodbc on Mac and Windows, even talking to each other, for years.